# Getting errors when downloading blob in a VM(Ubuntu) in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I am not sure why this isn't working when trying to download in the VM, but I am able to download the same when pasting the URL in a browser

These are the steps

Create Storage Account. Inside that created a Container. Inside that container uploaded a zipped file as a Blob. I then generated a SAS token and get a Blob SAS URL.

With this URL, when I do the following in the VM via command line

```
wget <url>
```

I get

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 The specified resource does not exist.
2020-07-11 23:05:40 ERROR 404: The specified resource does not exist..
```

However I paste that same URL in a browser outside the VM, the file gets downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using fileshares inside Storage Accounts. I uploaded the file in file shares, then hit Connect, got the connection commands, ran that in the VM and my files were there